# R/Shiny WebApp logs, running in shell (Ubuntu crontab)

Tags: r, ubuntu, logging, shiny, cron

I'm running, using crontab, an R/Shiny WebApp. The crontab expression looks like this:

```
@reboot R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)' | tee /var/log/shiny-server.log
```

I've also tried

```
@reboot R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)' &> /var/log/shiny-server.log
```

but does the same: It prints to the file the header when you initialize R from shell. But it doesn't print any text about the page, i.e. when it loads, when it uploads something, when it crashes...

Do you know how to pipe the output of the logs of the WebApp to the file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been searching in the web and I didn't find any solution.

Instead, I changed the philosophy. I generated myself some logs from inside the Shiny app with the help of the `sink()` function.

Thank you.